# Gdrive API : The user does not have sufficient permissions for this file

Tags: google-drive-api

I try to test Google Drive API from here : https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/drives/create

But I get this error : **The user does not have sufficient permissions for this file**
See also image below :

[image]

I don't understand why because I'm logged in with my Google Account, which admin of drive.

here is the code :

```
curl --request POST \ 
'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/drives?requestId=1234' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer [ACCESS_TOKEN]' \
--header 'Accept: application/json' \
--data '{"kind":"drive#drive","name":"TEST_DRIVE"}' \
--compressed
```

2. Another test : If I create a file at root level of my drive, works fine. here is the code :

   curl --request POST 
   'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files' 
   --header 'Authorization: Bearer [ACCESS_TOKEN]' 
   --header 'Accept: application/json' 
   --header 'Content-Type: application/json' 
   --data '{"kind":"drive#file","name":"TEST"}' 
   --compressed

And here the result :

```
200
{
 "kind": "drive#file",
 "id": "1Itd9QAK_YakAbw9JU4sD8ioa7wBZ8Xud",
 "name": "TEST",
 "mimeType": "application/octet-stream"
}
```

3. other test again : If I want to list my folders at root level of my drive, I get nothing. here is the code :

   curl 
   'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/drives' 
   --header 'Authorization: Bearer [ACCESS_TOKEN]' 
   --header 'Accept: application/json' 
   --compressed

Here is the result :

```
{
 "kind": "drive#driveList",
 "drives": []
}
```

Do you have any idea?

Thanks
L.

Comment: Your admin of the gsuite account?

Comment: I have added the code generated by Google API Explorer.

Comment: When I launch this code, a popup is displayed asking me to choose the Gmail account I want to use, and I select the right account who the owner of the account.

Comment: add yes my account is super admin

Comment: another point : I am able to create FILES here https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create but not drives..and also, when I try to list my drives I get a blank page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution found.
files end-point have to be used and not drives to create folder.
code below works :

```
curl --request POST \
  'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer [ACCESS_TOKEN]' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data '{"name":"TEST","mimeType":"application/vnd.google-apps.folder"}' \
  --compressed
```

So what is the difference between drives and folders ?